# In order to show that a function is C^1 is it enough to show that the 1. partial derivatives exists?

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity, implicit-function-theorem

Hello I am having some issues with the following exercise:

Let $\textbf{h}: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ given by

$\large \textbf{h}(u,v) = u^2 + (v-1)^2 - 5 + e^{u-2}$

(i) Show that $\textbf{h}(2,1) = 0$ and $\textbf{h}\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$

$\large \textbf{h}(2,1) = 2^2 + (1-1)^2 - 5 + e^{2-2} = 4+0-5+1 = 0$

and next I show that $\textbf{h}\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$. I start out by showing that the partial derivatives exists:

\begin{align*}
\large \textbf{h}_u(u, v)=& \lim_{k\to 0}\frac{\textbf{h}(u+k, v)- \textbf{h}(u,v)}{k}\\
 =& \lim_{k\to 0}\frac{\left((u+k)^2 + (v-1)^2 - 5 + e^{(u+k)-2}\right)- \left((u)^2 + (v-1)^2 - 5 + e^{(u-2)}\right)}{k}\\ 
=& \lim_{k\to 0}\frac{(u+k)^2 + (v-1)^2 - 5 + e^{(u+k)-2} - (u)^2 - (v-1)^2 + 5 - e^{(u-2)}}{k}\\ 
=& \lim_{k\to 0}\frac{(u+k)^2 + e^{(u+k)-2} - (u)^2 - e^{(u-2)}}{k}\\ 
=& \lim_{k\to 0}\left(2(u+k) + e^{(u+k)-2}\right)\\
=& \lim_{k\to 0}\left(2u+2k + e^{(u+k)-2}\right)\\
=& 2u + 0 + e^{(u+0)-2}\\
= & 2u + e^{(u-2)}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\large \textbf{h}_v(u, v)=& \lim_{k\to 0}\frac{\textbf{h}(u, v+k)- \textbf{h}(u,v)}{k}\\
 =& \lim_{k\to 0}\frac{\left(u^2 + ((v+k)-1)^2 - 5 + e^{(u-2)}\right)- \left((u)^2 + (v-1)^2 - 5 + e^{(u-2)}\right)}{k}\\ 
 =& \lim_{k\to 0}\frac{((v+k)-1)^2 - (v-1)^2}{k}\\ 
=& \lim_{k\to 0}\frac{(v+k)^2+1-2(v+k) - v^2-1+2v}{k}\\ 
=& \lim_{k\to 0}\frac{v^2+k^2 + 2vk+1-2v-2k - v^2-1+2v}{k}\\ 
=& \lim_{k\to 0}\frac{k^2 + 2vk-2k}{k}\\
=& \lim_{k\to 0}\left(2k + 2v-2\right) \\
=&2(v-1)
\end{align*}

And now since I have shown that the partial derivatives exists I can conclude that $h(u,v) \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Is this correct and enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $h$ (not ${\bf h}$, since $h$ is scalar-valued) is $C^\infty$ "by inspection".

The existence of the partial derivatives $h_u(u_0,v_0)$, $\>h_v(u_0,v_0)$ is *necessary, but not sufficient,* for the differentiability of $h$ at $(u_0,v_0)$.  Examples like
$$h(u,v):={uv\over u^2+v^2}\quad\bigl((u,v)\ne(0,0)\bigr),\qquad h(0,0):=0$$
have appeared many times on MSE.

The following fact, however, takes care of $99\%$ of the cases: If the partial derivatives $h_u$, $h_v$ exist and are continuous on the open set $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ then $h$ is continuously differentiable, in short: $C^1$, on $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
I think that the map $h$ is composite of three $C^{\infty}$ function and by chain rule the map $h$ is $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: Do you mean that I can write $\textbf{h}(u,v) = g(u) + f(v) + w(u)$ where $g(u) = u^2$, $f(v) = (v−1)^2−5$ and $w(u) = e^{u−2}$? And use this to say that  $\textbf{h}(u,v)$ must be continous?

Comment: The thing is that our professor wants us to use partial derivatives to show this, so I am trying to understand how I can solve the exercise using partial derivatives.

Comment: I have updated my question, is it correct or and enough to show that the partial derivatives exist?

Comment: Not in general, but since your partial derivatives are continuous, the "total derivative" must exist. Whether you understand and are allowed to use this theorem is another matter. If you are just starting with total derivatives, the point might be to have you grapple with the the definition and write down an actual matrix.

Comment: @cxseven How can I show that the total derivative must exist just by using the partial derivatives then? My professor used the Jacobian of $\textbf{h}$ to argue that it is $C^1$ however I cannot see how he can do this?

Comment: It looks like there is a proof at http://www-home.math.uwo.ca/~dfitzpa3/H53/Continuously_Differentiable.pdf